# Realm didn't match redirect_uri/origin. Error code: 2

Tags: google-oauth

When I use the following URI for the Google OAuth request I get error below:

> "Realm didn't match redirect_uri/origin. Error code: 2".

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=client_id_copied_from_the_developer_console&response_type=code&scope=openid%20email&redirect_uri=https://mysite.your-now.com/oauth2callback&state=security_token%3D138r5719ru3e1%26url%3Dhttps://mysite.your-now.com/navpage.do&login_hint=mycompany@gmail.com&openid.realm=your-now.com&hd=your-now.com

Comment: Did you register that uri with your project in google developer console? If you didn't, google won't let responses be redirected there as a security measure.

Comment: I did register it in the Developer Console under API's & Auth -> Credentials.  But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The realm value you are providing as openid.realm is malformed.

More specifically, the [openid4java match method](https://code.google.com/p/openid4java/source/browse/trunk/src/org/openid4java/server/RealmVerifier.java?r=631#212) is failing with a [MALFORMED_REALM](https://code.google.com/p/openid4java/source/browse/trunk/src/org/openid4java/server/RealmVerifier.java?r=631#31) result. Make sure you are providing a valid url as realm!

Hope that helps.

Comment: As mentioned in my response, a valid url.